# MongoDB: Валидация без использования Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, валидация, mongoose

### Ситуация

Мне нужно без использования модуля Mongoose сделать проверку на уникальность поля.
В Mongoose это определялось в схеме методом `unique`. Но вот как добиться такого же результата без использования этого модуля. Смотрел в официальной документации но не нашел ответа.

### Вопрос

Как перед созданием документа проверить его поле на уникальность? Есть ли какая валидация в MongoDB из коробки?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Answer (score 0):

Валидация в Монго вообще [здесь](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) и для Вашего случая в частности, но это уникальность только для индексированых полей (!!!):

```
db.runCommand( {
   collMod: "myCollection",
   validator: { $jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: "string",
      uniqueItems: "true"
   } },
   validationLevel: "moderate"
} )
```

В коллекции теперь есть валидатор со значением `validationLevel: moderate`.
Чтобы полностью отключить проверку - `validationLevel: off`.
Для любых полей https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator